# Как оформить foreach в теле письма mail()

Tags: email, php, foreach

Всем привет!

Целый день рышу по Сети, бьюсь, но не могу найти ответа на вопрос: как можно устроить foreach в теле письма? Если в корзине, в заказе идёт два товара двумя строчками, то в письмо клиенту отправляется только одна строчка с последним товаром. Как я понимаю, нужно пробежаться прямо в письме по товарам, но вот как это сделать? Здесь foreach не работает - письмо вообще не отправляется, но ошибок никаких php не выдаёт:

```
<?php
...
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && isset($_POST['order'])) { 
         $name = $_POST['name'];
        $s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $title = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($product['title'])), 0, 1000); 
        $price =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($product['price'],2)), 0, 1000000); 
        $qty = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($quantity)), 0, 1000); 
        $size = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($b['size'])), 0, 1000); 
        $tprice =  substr(htmlspecialchars(trim(number_format($product['price'] * $quantity ,2))), 0, 1000000); 
        // $to - кому отправляем 
        $to = $_POST['email'] . ', '; // обратите внимание на запятую
        $to .= 'arhat78@yandex.ru';

        // тема письма
        $subject = "=?utf-8?B?". base64_encode("Новый заказ"). "?=";

        // текст письма
   $message  = 'Сообщение от пользователя <b>'.$name.'</b><br /><br />';

   $message .= 'Имя: ' . $name . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Фамилия: ' . $s_name . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Адрес: ' . $address . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Почта: ' . $email . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Телефон: ' . $phone . '<br /><br />';

   $message .= 'Артикул: ' . $title . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Размер: ' . $size . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Цена: ' . $price . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Количество: ' . $qty . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Общая сумма: ' . $tprice . '<br />';
   $message .= 'Комментарий: ' . $comment . '<br /><br /><br /><br />';

         $message .='<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Товар</th>
        <th>Размер</th>
        <th>Цена</th>
        <th>Кол-во</th>
        <th>Всего</th>
    </tr>';

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
    $product = get_product($id);

    $b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id];

    $message .='
    <tr>
        <td align="center">' . $product['title'] . '</td>
        <td align="center"> ' . $b['size'] . '</td>
        <td align="center">' . number_format($product['price'], 2) . 'руб' . '</td>
        <td align="center">' . $quantity . '</td>
        <td align="center">' . number_format($product['price'] * $quantity, 2) . 'руб' . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
$message .= '</table>';

   ...     
?>
```

Письмо на почту не приходит и при проверке через if-else выводится "Ошибка!!!", которая стоит в else.  Значит что то с foreach не правильно....

Заранее благодарен :)

Comment: Непонятно, что вы вообще спрашиваете.
Форичем пробегайтесь по каждому товару.
Стройте точно также html код, заносите его в переменную.
Потом отправляйте письмо.

Что значит в вашем понимании "foreach внедрить в тело письма"?

Comment: @arhat78, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Как бы это объяснить....   Вот когда я вставляю первый код (из заказа) в письмо, то пишет ошибку, что не известен 'cart'  и foreach :  Notice: Undefined index: cart in ;  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...

Comment: Какой то непонятный вопрос. Непонятно , что и где начинается, плохо оформлен код. 

Comment: В первом вопросе исправил и добавил код. 

В чём проблем - если проходить без цикла в письме, то из всех заказов на почту приходит таблица только с одним последним заказом, а если вот так прохожусь с foreach, то появляются вышеуказанные ошибки....

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что переменная $_SESSION['cart'] не определена.
Ищите почему. В предоставленном обновленном примере кода причину не видно, она где-то выше.

Comment: Весь код в 200 строчек неудобно здесь выставлять, наверно.....

Comment: $_SESSION['cart'] является ли массивом?

Comment: Ну до этого с этой сессией всё было в порядке. Сейчас перед формой письма изменил код на этот:

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && isset($_POST['order'])

и ошибки пропали, но письмо на почту не приходит... Попробую подключить вывод ошибок при неудаче отправки письма...

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас сессия в этотм моент существует?

Comment: Мне кажется, тут уже и автор и отвечающие запутались, в чем проблема.
@arhat78, http://phpfaq.ru/debug и подтяните синтаксис языка.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value){
    statement
}
```

Вот синтаксис foreach. У вас там какое двоеточие....

```
<?php

$message .='<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Товар</th>
        <th>Размер</th>
        <th>Цена</th>
        <th>Кол-во</th>
        <th>Всего</th>
    </tr>';

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
    $product = get_product($id);

    $b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id];

    $message .='
    <tr>
        <td align="center">' . $product['title'] . '</td>
        <td align="center"> ' . $b['size'] . '</td>
        <td align="center">' . number_format($product['price'], 2) . 'руб' . '</td>
        <td align="center">' . $quantity . '</td>
        <td align="center">' . number_format($product['price'] * $quantity, 2) . 'руб' . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
$message .= '</table>';
```

> Автор:
> print_r($_SESSION) выводит: Array (
> [total_items] => 1 [total_price] =>
> 600 [cart_size] => Array ( [2] => 19 )
> )

на данный момент у вас не существует переменной $_SESSION['cart'], соответственно цикл не разу не выполняется...

Comment: Поменял, но тоже "Ошибка!!!"....

Comment: Я не знаю структуру ваших переменных, покажите, что за ошибка.

Comment: "Ошибка!!!" - это у меня выводится, если отправка письма не произошла.  А сам php никаких ошибок не показывает, просто письмо не отправляется.

Comment: Это уже совсем другая история. Посмотрите, работает ли функция mail() вообще. Пропишите свои данные "ручками", если не работает, обращайтесь к хостеру.

Comment: Если я уберу вот этот код:

    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity){
             $product = get_product($id);

             $b['size'] = $_SESSION['cart_size'][$id];}

то всё прекрасно отправляется, но только с одним последним заказанным товаром из нескольких.

Comment: print_r($_SESSION['cart']) покажи результат

Comment: Ничего не пишет. Или вообще пусто, или Notice: Undefined index: cart in , но это при разных вариациях, когда не туда этот print_r вставляю....

Comment: у вас не существует переменной $_SESSION['cart'], соответственно цикл не разу не выполняется...
update::
Не видя кода, я ничего не могу сказать.

Answer (score 0):

У вас фореачиться заголовок таблицы. Сначала соберите весь html в строковую переменную, ПЕРЕД вставкой в сообщение.Или вы себе представляете, что фореач уже будет отрабатывать приходя на почту?

Comment: А вот это я не понял... Почему только заголовок? Вроде нужные данные находятся внутри foreach{}....

Comment: Попробуйте для начала собрать все в переменную и вывести просто на странице, а уже потом пихайте ее в сообщение.
     <tr><th>Товар</th>...</tr> - Вот эта вот часть у вас в фореаче, она тоже продублируется.

Comment: Да, про дублирование понял.  А вот как это мой html поместить в переменную, а потом её же поместить в message .=''; , пока не догнал....

Comment: Не получается выше комментировать и добавлять код в комментах, добавлю весь код страницы в моём первом вопросе.